# Can I pass a param to the next routed URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

If a url is `localhost:3000/rooms/:token` has a key in the params at this point named `:token`,
in the `#show` method in the controller I can ```params.merge!({ dev_paramater: 'hello'}) that would be present in the params when calling `localhost:3000/rooms/:token`, but when I go to `localhost:3000/rooms/:token/chats` the `dev_parameter` key disappears from params.

I would like to use data in the `dev_parameter`, I basically want it to persist if I visit deeper routes.

Answer (score 0):

`params` is provided by the controller according to the request content when requests are received, they are independent in each requests. (BTW, `params` should not be modified in most cases.) If you need carry some information between requests, consider using `session` or `cookies` instead.

Rails guide:

session - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

cookies - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#cookies

Comment: I am using rails API without a User model, so sessions and cookies are not an option unfortunately.

Comment: You may misunderstand the `user` term in rails guides, `session` and `cookies` have nothing to do with the User model and can work without it. They are just implemented with the standard HTTP cookie (see MDN doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies ) .